# Raspberry Pi and python real time

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am working on Raspberry pi and getting real time signals like distance. I would like to use the distance to make other decisions such as drive left or right etc. I am using the while loop as given below. The problem is that while I am executing the if statement, it does not know the current measured distance until the if loop ends. How can I check distance parallel manner and make decision based on it? For example, at any given time if the distance is less than 50cm, then stop the car or tun away etc. I have looked into threading and timer, but not sure how to utilize it here.

```
def main():
        while True:
        distance =measuredDistance(TRIGGER, ECHO, time)
        print('Distance: ', distance)
        sleep(1)
        if distance > 50:   
            allStop()
            print("Driving Forward")
            forwardDrive(0.5, 0.5)
            sleep(5)
            allStop()
            sleep(5)
            print("Driving Reverse")
            reverseDrive(0.4, 0.4)
            sleep(5)
            allStop()
            sleep(5)
        else:
            allStop()
```